# Why does python have a pre-increment operator but not post-increment?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i tried using pre-increment operator(++var_name) in python 3.7.1 and it doesn't produce any Syntaxerror unlike post-increment operator (var_name++) which produced a Syntaxerror.Can someone explain this??

```
count = 0
++count
print(count)
```

and the output is :

```
0
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

but when i use post-increment the output was different

```
count = 0
count++
print(count)

t
```

he output is :

```
 count++
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Answer (score 3):

Python does not have an increment operator, pre or post. `++count` is interpreted as two operations of the unary `+` operator: `(+(+count))`, which does nothing here, so the result is 0.

To increment, the only option is to use the in-place addition operator, and increment by 1:

```
count += 1
```

Comment: Do you know if there's any use for the unary `+` operator other than for explicitly marking a value as positive? I've seen it used in cases like `neg_var = -10` and `pos_var = +10`, but never once outside of that.

Comment: @NickChapman The same purpose it would have in most other languages, I assume. Except with python, you can probably overload it for objects to provide more useful behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't support ++, but you can do:

count += 1